# DropDownGallery Object?

Tags: wpf, ribbon

I was trying to follow this link to set up a drop down gallery on my ribbon bar using wpf and c#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742868(v=VS.85).aspx

I cannot seem to initialize the dropdowngallery object on my ribbon bar in the xaml there is no option to create one... I have access to all the other ribbon controls besides the gallery controls in the xaml. There is a RibbonGallery object but not any specific gallery controls (DropDown, SplitButton, In-Ribbon) Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/04/how-do-i-add-galleries-to-my-ribbon.aspx) includes an example of how to add a Ribbon gallery in WPF. The link you include in your question is for the Win32/MFC version of the Ribbon control, which is different.